# Export crystal report into pdf in vb without using form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I'm a newbie to VB and Crystal Reports.

I want to make an `.exe` file in VB.NET that doesn't use a Form.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010.
The `.exe` file is just purely for exporting a Crystal Report into a `.pdf` file, where should I start?

Should I use the `console application`?

Should I use the `empty project code`?

I have searched the internet and cannot find any references.

Please let me know if there is a Reference that I can refer to.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use a console app or a forms app but just don't display the form. I tend to point people to the code samples at: http://vb.net-informations.com/crystal-report/vb.net_crystal_report_export_pdf.htm

```
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
Public Class Form1
    Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        cryRpt.Load("PUT CRYSTAL REPORT PATH HERE\CrystalReport1.rpt")
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt
        CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Try
            Dim CrExportOptions As ExportOptions
            Dim CrDiskFileDestinationOptions As New _
            DiskFileDestinationOptions()
            Dim CrFormatTypeOptions As New PdfRtfWordFormatOptions()
            CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = _
                                        "c:\crystalExport.pdf"
            CrExportOptions = cryRpt.ExportOptions
            With CrExportOptions
                .ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile
                .ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat
                .DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions
                .FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions
            End With
            cryRpt.Export()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank u very much lee.Now i can have a breif idea.